# How to include a variable value as a part of url in php

Tags: php

```
 $imagefilename=$row['uimage'];
```

i.e storing the url of an image from table to variable imagefilename

now i wish to use that file name and fetch the image from its location by using the command

```
 echo '<a href="update/update.php"><img id="unregistered" src="php/customer/customer_images/{$imagefilename}"/></a>';
```

but its not considering "$imagefilename" as a part of the url could some one please tell me how to make this happen thanks!

Comment: You need to use `"` instead `'` or you write it like this `echo 'sometext'.$var.'someothertext';`

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, you might also be able to only inject the variable into your actual HTML: `<a href="#"><img src="/some/dir/<?= $file ?>"></a>`

Answer (score 2):

Append the php variable using single quote like below:

```
echo '<a href="update/update.php"><img id="unregistered" src="php/customer/customer_images/'.$imagefilename.'/></a>';
```

Comment: bhat i tried your code but there is one little bug "http://localhost/AirBnb/php/customer/customer_images/IMG-20140414-WA0000.jpg/%3E%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20href=" in my db the value stored is only "IMG-20140414-WA0000.jpg" but its adding /%3E%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20href= extra i dono where it comes from can you help me please

Comment: Try `urldecode()` source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Yes as suggested by @Spirit. Try that it will work

Comment: @AravindBhatK could you please tell how to include that urldecode() in the src double quotes

Comment: @Spirit could you please tell how to include that urldecode() in the src double quotes

Comment: Try like this: echo '<a href="update/update.php"><img id="unregistered" src="php/customer/customer_images/'.urldecode($imagefilename).'/></a>';

Comment: You can use the option from @AravindBhatK or work with a lambda function: `$myfunc = function($text) { echo urldecode($text); }; echo "somtext{$myfunc($var)}";`

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
  <?php
$imagefilename = "file1.jpg";
   echo '<a href="update/update.php"><img id="unregistered" src="php/customer/customer_images/'.$imagefilename.'/></a>';

   echo "\n";

   echo "OR";

   echo "\n";

   $imagefilename = "php/customer/customer_images/file1.jpg";

   echo "https://localhost/folderName/update/update.php?$imagefilename";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here all the Comments in one Answer:

```
//Your image url
$var = 'my%20text';

// echo with ' and urldecode
echo 'sometext '.urldecode($var).' someothertext';

//lambda function with urldecode
$myfunc = function($text) {
    echo urldecode($text);
};

// working echo with {} (needs lambda function)
echo "somtext{$myfunc($var)}";
```